# Upload web app to tomcat using Java

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, automation

In my unit test I am using **org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat** to deploy a web app. I am able to deploy a webapp with .war format without any problem.
But in my case I want to add a value from java code to index.html of the webapp and then upload. So I can't stick with .war format for this. I tried to upload the web app as directory.Following is my java code to upload the "examplewebapp" as directory.

```
    String appPath="/home/examplewebapp"; // webapp
    String currentDir = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
    String tomcatDir = currentDir + File.separatorChar + "tomcat";


    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setBaseDir(tomcatDir);
    tomcat.setPort(4040);
    tomcat.addWebapp("/examplewebapp", appPath);        
    tomcat.start();
```

but web app is not deployed on server as expected. I need to know whether
tomcat.addWebapp() method supports only to .war format or there is any bug in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is two errors in the above code

first yon didn't path to the correct folder ( String appPath="/home/examplewebapp"; // webapp)

second you need to call 
  tomcat.getServer().await(); after tomcat.start(); because the server will quit after it start.

see the below example

String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

```
    //The port that we should run on can be set into an environment variable
    //Look for that variable and default to 8080 if it isn't there.
    String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
    if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
        webPort = "8080";
    }

    tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

    tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" + webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you guidance . Now it works fine. the thing I missed was
tomcat.getServer().await()

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Consult [Lars Vogel's 4th chapter of his tutorial how to add Tomcat in Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWTP/article.html#configuration) and follow his instructions.

Step 2: Click on your Web Project and go to step 3.

[image: Click on Web Project]

Step 3: Click Run and let Eclipse start your Tomcat.

[image: Click Run]

Step 4: Select 'Run on Server' and continue with OK.

[image: Run on server]

Step 5: Choose existing Server and optionally enable the check box.

[image: Choose existing server]

Step 6: Enjoy!

[image: enjoy]